# Is there a way to determine if drawerPanel is open or closed?

Tags: javascript, polymer

Or rather, a native method already defined in polymer source? I'm sure I could write up a function to handle the logic pretty easily, but I've done some digging and haven't come up with anything regarding an already implemented method of determining this. Just want to know if I'll have to write up something myself or not.

Edit: Just realized, even if I did write a tagalong function that tracks when the drawer is opened/closed via `toggleDrawer()`, it'd get thrown off when the drawer is swiped open or swiped closed, so I sure hope there is a native method for this.

Edit: Using info from the page @Justin XL linked me, I did some testing and found that general opening of closing of the drawer, via swipe, or drawer button press, fired 2 core-selected events, but closing via clicking a drawer item fired 4. I've managed to throw together a solution that should be able to determine at any point if the drawer is open or closed based on 2 vars.

```
drawerOpenIgnoreClose = false;
drawerOpen = false;
drawerEvent = 0;
drawer.addEventListener('core-select', function() {
    drawerEvent++;
    //console.log('drawerpanel event fired ' + drawerEvent);
    if (drawerEvent >= 2) {
        if (drawerOpenIgnoreClose) {
            drawerOpenIgnoreClose = false;
            console.log('drawer is closed, not from click of menu item');
        } else {
            drawerOpenIgnoreClose = true;
            console.log('drawer is open');
        }
        drawerEvent = 0;
    }
});
```

And `drawerOpen` is set to false every time `drawerPanel.closerDrawer()` is called, which is every time a menu item is clicked. I can then determine for certain if the drawer is open with

```
function checkDrawer() {
    if (drawerOpen && drawerOpenIgnoreClose) {
        console.log('drawer is definitely open');
        return true;
    } else if (!drawerOpen || !drawerOpenIgnoreClose) {
        console.log('drawer is definitely closed');
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's yet to fail me with a button outside of the drawer and a button inside the drawer that run `checkDrawer()` (both return open/closed respectively), but I'll do some more testing. I don't even know if this is the simplest or even correct way of handling this but it seems to work and I'm happy.

Edit again: Managed to find an issue, if the drawer panel is swiped open, `checkDrawer()` will return closed. More logic will fix it I'm sure. gonna make some adjustments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you meant `core-drawer-panel`.

There's a `narrow` attribute which tells you whether the panel is in a narrow layout or not.

Alternatively, you can subscribe to `core-responsive-change` event and use `detail.narrow` to determine.

You can read more from [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-drawer-panel.attributes.narrow).

Comment: Using the information provided, I've written up some code that I think presents a viable solution and added it to the original question post. It's working in all my testing so far, so thank you for your help! I wish I could upvote your answer but I'm still lacking in rep. Once/if I get up there I will definitely come back and upvote :D

Comment: It seems I will likely end up turning off swipe to open drawer and scrap this whole bit because swiping throws off the logic every time. It's very frustrating. Either way, this was a good bit of insight, so thanks again. I've upvoted now that I'm able to.